# AppleScript command "on will finish launching" no longer a thing?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to build a script that I wrote back in 2005...  It's yelling at me about:

`on will finish launching theObject`

> Expected “given”, “into”, “with”, “without” or other parameter name but found identifier. (-2741)

Is there another way to delay a code block until launch?

Comment: That looks like something from the old **AppleScript Studio**, which was deprecated in Snow Leopard and has since been completely removed.  The current framework is **AppleScriptObjC**, which uses method signatures closer to Objective-C, so that one would be `on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification`.

Comment: ok, well after dealing with that, I still have a bunch of other errors..  It appears that since Applescript has changed so much since I wrote this, it's time for a complete rewrite in a different language.  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much only the regular AppleScript parts will be reusable.  The old AppleScript Studio used wrappers around the supported Cocoa terminology, while AppleScriptObjC calls them more-or-less directly (after slight conversions to AppleScript syntax) - see the [Translation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AppendixA-AppleScriptObjCQuickTranslationGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH79-SW1) for more information.